# Multiple Regex expression

Tags: regex

I have a text like below:

```
CpuUtilization[GqIF:CA-TORONTO-1-AD-1 | FAULT-DOMAIN-1 | ocid1.image.oc1.ca-toronto-1.aaaaaaaanzxg2lycvtpzgobswpp3kht3byzc4kduvbuzks7u65r5zlyrzdaq | Default | ca-toronto-1 | Bastion | ocid1.instance.oc1.ca-toronto-1.an2g6ljrwe6j4fqcnimiwc5wkneq7x6zcd4m23emiv7scbx47za7bpht54la | VM.Standard.E3.Flex]
```

I want to extract the multiple texts like from the same expressions, like `CA-TORONTO-1-AD-1`, `Bastion` and `VM.Standard.E3.Flex`.

I can extract a single element using an expression

```
^(?:[^|]+ \| ){5}([^ ]+).*$
```

Question is, how can I combine regex expression into a single expression?

Comment: Exactly which "single element" do you want to extract from the sample text, and what determines why it is The One?

Comment: @Bohemian They don't want to extract a single element, that's the problem. They want to extract all of them.

Comment: `[^ |]+` will match anything that isn't space or `|`.

Comment: You can try such as [`(?:\[[^:|]+:|(?:(?: \| [^|]+){4}) \| | \| [^|]+ \| )([^\s|\]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/5IYVLQ/2) and grab [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of the first group. Please mention regex flavor (lang/tool) you're using.

Comment: Any special reason you have to use a regex? Why not just remove the first 15 chars (everything including the `[`) and the last char (`]`) and then split by `" | "`?

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, here is how you can concatenate regex:
^(?:[^|]+ | ){1}([^|]+) | [^|]+ | [^|]+ | [^|]+ | ([^|]+) | [^|]+ | ([^|]+)]

```
import re   
matches = re.search(r"^(?:[^|]+ \| ){1}([^|]+) \| [^|]+ \| [^|]+ \| 
              [^|]+ \| ([^|]+) \| [^|]+ \| ([^|]+)\]", string)
if matches:
   my_data_values_grp = [matches.group(1), matches.group(2), 
                                                matches.group(3)]
   print(data)
```